# CSS3 keyframe jumps to end of animation without animating

Tags: css, css-animations

In the linked fiddle, an element has two animations.

https://jsfiddle.net/ccqpLa6L/1/

Below is a capture of the CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes slideInLeft { 0% { transform: translateX(-200px);  } 100% { transform: translateX(0); } }
@-webkit-keyframes slideOutLeft { 0% { transform: translateX(0); } 100% { transform: translateX(100px); }}

.element {
    width: 250px;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: dimgrey;
    right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-animation: slideInLeft 1s forwards, slideOutLeft 2s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s, 1s;
}
```

The first animation executes without an issue, but the second animation jumps to the end of its animation without any interstitial frames.

Why?

Comment: It's been about 1 year since I asked this question, but reviewing the fiddle provided it is no longer an issue. That leads me to assume that it must have been a browser issue, which is no longer present.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not exactly sure why the animation wasn't running properly, I was able to achieve the desired effect using spaced out percentages in one keyframe:

https://jsfiddle.net/ccqpLa6L/5/

```
@-webkit-keyframes slideInLeft { 
    0% { 
        transform: translateX(-200px);  
    } 
    25% {
        transform: translateX(0); 
    }
    50% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% { 
        -webkit-transform: translateX(100px); 
    } 
}

.element {
    width: 250px;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: dimgrey;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-animation: slideInLeft 4s forwards;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need this to be two discreet keyframe blocks as timing will vary depending on the keyframe.